# Why does getting error in ReactApplication

Tags: android, react-native

I am facing following Error

> > Cannot find symbol class ReactApplication

```
package com.testreactapp;

import android.app.Application;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

 private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {

}
```

Comment: add some code as well

Comment: I just make simple app in react native . And when run these error is appeared .

Comment: here is the code : <code>package com.testreactapp;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

 private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
   
}

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if [this](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/314) can solve your problem:

this can be solved by adding this in `android/build.gradle` :

```
maven {
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
```

Also you need to re-do `npm i` afterward.

Comment: can you put all your steps(to reproduce), I can do it in mine and see the issue.